# Connection refused with implicit tls proftpd on Azure VM

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-virtual-machine, ftps, proftpd

We have a proftpd server on an AzureVM configured to use implicit ftps.

Error:

> Status:   Connecting to myPublicIP:990...
>   Status:   Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by > server".
>   Error:    Could not connect to server

**Relevant configuration**

```
# /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
Port                            21
PassivePorts                  49152 49190
MasqueradeAddress               myPublicIP

# /etc/proftpd/tls.conf
TLSEngine                               on
TLSLog                                  /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
TLSProtocol                             TLSv1 TLSv1.2
TLSCipherSuite AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
#TLSOptions                 NoCertRequest AllowClientRenegotiations UseImplicitSSL EnableDiags
TLSRSACertificateFile      /etc/proftpd/ssl/certificate.pem
TLSRSACertificateKeyFile   /etc/proftpd/ssl/certificate.key
TLSVerifyClient            off
TLSRequired                on
```

I have open the following ports in the security group and interface of the virtual machine:

> 20,21,49152-49190,990,989.

If I do not force the connection through the implicit port, the rest of the connections works perfectly

Comment: Refer to the suggestion mentioned in this article:http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configure-ftp-and-use-custom-domain-on-azure-vm/

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your configuration, you did not enable implicit. If you execute `netstat -ant|grep 990`, it should return null.

So, if you use port to connect ftp server, you will get the error log.

You could check this link to enable implicit.

```
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
    Port 990
    TLSEngine on
    TLSOptions UseImplicitSSL
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Then you need restart ftp server, `service xinetd restart`

When you execute `netstat -ant|grep 990`, you will get like below:

```
root@shui:~# netstat -ant|grep 990
tcp6       0      0 :::990                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: I dont know why dont work listen on port 990, the directive ```Port 8990``` and open port 8990 in the firewall solved the problem!